# Extended kalman filter for accelerometer data on shaking table

Tags: noise, kalman-filters

I am using an accelerometer to record the motion of a shake table (a rocking table) which moves forward and backward in one direction. The signal is very noisy and decided to use Extended Kalman Filter. What equation should i use for the model?

Comment: Why do you think you need an extended Kalman filter? What is non-linear about the motion?

Comment: since it is rocking table, i thought it is non linear. the displacement is described by x = a sin(wt)

Comment: To my way of thinking, that sine wave is the *excitation* (or input) of the system. It does not describe how the table reacts to stimulus.  The reaction of the table to stimulus will be (approximately) linear, so the EKF is probably not needed.

Comment: i got the idea after reading the last part of [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4758/2012sp/materials/MI63slides.pdf)

Comment: [this one](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/media/pdf/kftool_models.pdf) also talks about sloshing, is it similar to the motion of the table?

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the links.  Even with the extra sinusoidal part of the model, it's not clear to me that the estimation is much better.  Have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8869/80), and see if just a straightforward Kalman filter can improve the situation.