# Kalman Filter to estimate 3D position of a node

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, non-linear

Code given on this link works for 1D:
[Kalman filter for position and velocity: introducing speed estimates](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/more-on-kalman-filter-for-position-and-velocity/8869#8869)

In my problem I need to estimate 3D position.What is the criteria ?

How F, G ,H,Q and R change in 3D case.
This problem is restricted to estimate position only  (No velocity,No acceleration).What measurement vector should contain.Only positions?
Please respond!I am sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: Why do you think filtering is involved in this question at all?  There is no time-dependence on any of the quantities you outline.  Note that I have changed some of the notation... you originally had two $r_1$s which confused me.  I changed it so that $d_k = | r - r_k|$ etc.

Comment: @PeterK.I understand what you mean.So my point is how I can use Kalman filter for 3D case.Is there any example or some explanation please.I am sorry if I said some thing wrong.

Comment: That's the problem: I can't see where filtering comes in here. This  is just an arithmetic problem.

Comment: @PeterK. Could you please mention 3D example in Kalman Filter.I know basics of KF but would like to see how it works for 3D case.Please if you know any example  would be nice of you.

Comment: Just use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application.2C_technical)  but augment the state as $\mathbf{x}_k = [ x\ \dot{x}\ y\ \dot{y}\ z\ \dot{z} ]^T$

Comment: @PeterK.Thansk for sharing the information.I will go through it.

Comment: @PeterK.Thanks for posting the link.It contains so much useful information regarding the derivation of KF equations. Kindly would so nice if you post a 3D example of Matlab implementation of KF please. I see some examples available on internet but are so complicated .Could you post a Matlab example please. Thanks in advance! Sorry for any inconvenience!

Comment: [Haider, check out this answer.](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8869/80) It just does the 1D case, but 3D just extends this as I indicated above.

Comment: @PeterK. Thanks for posting the 1D example.I will go through it and see what happens. Thanks again

Comment: @PeterK. I have just gone through this 1D example of the given code.In that code in last for loop they have used a function called kalm() .But when I run this code in Matlab it says  " Undefined function or method 'kalm' for input arguments of type 'double'." Is this function not defined in Matlab or I am making some mistake while running.Please would be so nice if you clarify it kindly.Thanks!

Comment: http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/sCiMake/source/tree/885da23a2652da788a995392149af0403c3fde40/scilab-5.2.0/modules/signal_processing/macros/kalm.sci

Comment: Is there more that needs to be answered?

Comment: @PeterK. I am working on it if I have some thing to ask will write over here.Thanks for your notice

Comment: Was there anything else needed here?  I'm just trying to close out questions with no accepted answer.  If you need more info, please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, just [follow the 1D case from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application.2C_technical) and augment it with the extra $y$ and $z$ dimensions (and velocities):
$$
\mathbf{x}_k = \left [ 
\begin{array}{c}
x\\ \dot{x}\\ y\\ \dot{y}\\ z\\ \dot{z} 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

You will also need to augment $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{G}$:
$$
\mathbf{F} = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & \Delta t & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta t & 0 &  0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &        1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta t \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &        1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\mathbf{G} = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
\frac{\Delta t^2}{2}\\
\Delta t\\
\frac{\Delta t^2}{2}\\
\Delta t\\
\frac{\Delta t^2}{2}\\
\Delta t\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

And then $\mathbf{H}$ is just
$$
\mathbf{H} = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
so that $\mathbf{z}_k$ is
$$
\mathbf{z}_k =  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment I will do that and see.Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I have just one problem .I have run the code for 1D in Matlab but it gives me NAN result. I dont know why thins error exist .Would be so nice if you help please.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that sounds like a debugging issue... Are your $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ matrices singular? Did you set the initial covariance matrix to be non-singular?

Comment: Peter K:Thanks for your help.I am trying to run this code for 3D position.You said I need velocities in my xk vector (see above your comment).In my case I am just dealing with position (No velocity NO acceleration).Do I still need to add velocities .In my case I do not have information about velocity (I only have measured 3D position).And If I do not add velocities how does it effect the dimensions of F, G and H. Please help..Thanks

Comment: On which criteria Q and R should be chosen (values and dimensions) in 3D case.Please respond thanks.

Comment: Are you just measuring position for $x$, $y$, and $z$? Then the signal model above should work. $\mathbf{z}_k$ are your measurements.  If your model has no velocity, then the position won't change. If your model has not acceleration input, then the velocity won't change and so the position won't change.

Comment: Peter K:Thanks for the reply.Yes.I am just measuring position for x,y and z.You mean  this model should work without velocity and acceleration?Then what should be xk and F,G,H,Q and R.Please respond.I am sorry if I say some thing silly

Comment: The model assumes that only position is being measured. For the model to change the position, it needs to have a mechanism to do that: velocity and acceleration. Otherwise the position will not change.  The matrices above should work for the KF with your case.

Comment: Peter K thanks for your comment.In your comment kindly can you elaborate little bit more this line please:"For the model to change the position, it needs to have a mechanism to do that: velocity and acceleration".

Comment: @Haider : Does your object change its position?  If it does, then it has to have a velocity (change of position over time).

Comment: No my object does not change its position .What should I use in xk and other matrics F,G,H,Q and R please help.

Comment: The you don't need a Kalman filter.  Just keep averaging the position measurements you get.

Comment: Ok.Now I get your point.So if I want to use KF then it assumes the object changes its position and so needs velocity.This model only works if the object changes its position.Thanks Peter K .I will try it out and see and let you know