# Velocity estimation from distance sensor

Tags: matlab, filters, lowpass-filter, kalman-filters

I know it is a generic question but I did not find a specific answer to it online.

My question is:
I have a range sensor based on the time of flight (Infrared Sensor. Transmitter-Reflector-Receiver). I know the time at which I take my range measurements and I would like to get the velocity measurements.

Doing a simple derivative is not enough because the sensor gives me a lot of noise and therefore I would like to add a filter to my distance measurement and I would like to know **what is the best way to get velocity measurements from distance measurements (+time), which kind of filter would you use on the distance measurements before doing the derivative**.

My simple reply would be: "a low pass filter"
My slightly-more-complicated-reply would be: "a kalman filter, with acceleration equal to zero, which will be an optimal low pass filter if the acceleration is always around zero."

What do you think?

thanks for any advice!

Comment: [This question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26818/kalman-filter-velocity-matlab) shows how to implement a Kalman filter, though if you are sure the acceleration is zero you can probably simplify it.