# Application of UKF on quaternions

Tags: kalman-filters, state-space, unscented-kalman-filter

I'm trying to perform a state estimation on quaternions to predict the future orientation of a human head. The only sensor data I can obtain (from the AR headset) is the current orientation of the head, sampled at 200 Hz i.e. I don't have access to any gyroscope or acceloremeter data. After getting the state estimations, I would like to reuse the process/motion model (constant angular velocity) to make predictions further into the future, e.g. 20 ms to 100 ms.

Since the process model is nonlinear (due to quaternions), one option is to use an Unscented Kalman Filter (UKF). However, as discussed in [this](https://natanaso.github.io/ece276a2017/ref/2_Kraft_UKF.pdf) paper, quaternions cannot be directly used in the UKF and some conversions need to be made to obtain "quaternion sigma points" (Sec. 3.2 of the paper).

My question is, does it make sense at all to use this kind of method if I only have attitude measurements (quaternions) and no gyro or acceloremeter data? In this case, my state vector would be 7D: four quaternion and three angular velocity components. However, the paper (and most other works I encountered) always have some kind of gyro/acceloremeter measurements which makes me wonder if it's feasible to just have the attitude information and have the filter estimate the angular velocity.

Comment: If the amount of rotation between samples is small enough, an extended Kalman filter will do -- you don't need an Unscented kalman.  How small is "small enough" is hard to pin down, but 5 degrees or less is certainly small enough, 30 or 40 may still work, but 180 degrees is right out.

Comment: Usually when there's a Kalman filter driven by accelerometer and gyro data, then it's probably a GPS/IMU fusion algorithm -- but that's not the only sort of Kalman filter that might deal with rotations.

Comment: The amount of rotation between samples is around 0.1 degrees because this is head motion data and the sampling time is 5 ms (200 Hz). According to the literature, using EKF/UKF directly on quaternions doesn't seem to be the theoretically right way. Do you think that EKF on quaternions may work for small rotational changes between samples?

Comment: Just one paper hardly qualifies as "the literature" -- in particular, a paper by one author, with no publication information, may well be a senior project or part of a Master's thesis, and not peer reviewed at all.  Did you find a *bunch* of papers that indicated this?  Did you read them to make sure that the situations are the same?

Comment: I've used a "plain old" extended Kalman filter to deal with quaternions; it worked well except when the angular uncertainties were large.  In my case I went to an unscented -- the unscented was different only in that I had to choose a different way of selecting the sigma points.  In neither case did I find that I was butting heads with theory too hard (neither extended nor unscented approaches are "theoretically correct", btw -- they're both *approximations*, and as such will always be theeoretically suspect).

Comment: I suspect that a "plain old" extended will work for you, except that you want to make sure that your head set doesn't flip the quaternion 180 degrees between readings -- if it doesn't have any memory it may do that; if it *does* tend to do that then you'll need to test for it, and carry a "headset flipped" state.

Comment: I read a few highly-cited papers indicating the same issue and proposing adaptations of UKF/EKF such that they could be used on rotations. But of course, in practice it may be possible to get good results without delving too much into the theory. I've observed that even the standard (linear) Kalman filter seems to yield good estimations so I may not need an UKF/EKF in the end.

Comment: As you mentioned, I saw that my headset does flip the sign of the quaternions when one of the quaternion components approach 1. That makes my estimations to be off the mark at the points where the flips happen; I need to find a solution to this issue.

Comment: Basically, you need quaternions because any 3D angular representation with three elements will have singularities (do a web search on "hairy ball theorem").  But one of the prices you pay is that for any *one* 3D rotation, there are *two* quaternion values that represent it, i.e., for rotation $\mathbf{r}$, the quaternions $q$ and $-q$ will result in that rotation.  Hence, my suggestion to carry a "headset flipped" state (which can be true or false), which you can detect by seeing a sudden jump in the quaternion value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.  All that you'll need is to model how you think the angular velocity components of the state will evolve.  Usually simple brownian (random) motion is enough, at least to start with.  If you know more about how the angular velocities are constrained, then you can include that in the model.

All that it means is there are no outputs from your signal model directly from those elements of the state.

For example, in [this answer to another question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8869/80) the state is made up of the $x$ position and the $x$ velocity, but there is no velocity measurement.

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}_{k}  & =\left(\begin{array}[c]{c}x_{k}\\
\dot{x}_{k}\end{array}
\right)  
\end{align*}
$$

All that means is the output matrix $H$ zeros out that part of the state when producing the measurement.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand that I can include angular velocity into the state vector (as an unobserved state) even if I'm not getting any measurements of it. Another doubt I have is on the motion model for rotational motion. Does it make more sense to use the obtained quaternion representation directly and have a motion model that captures the relationship between the quaternion derivative and angular velocity, e.g. as described [here](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/quaternion-differentiation), or would it be also feasible to use the simple motion model in the answer you linked?

Comment: @chronosynclastic. I don't know enough about the advantages of the quaternion approach.  The thing the 1D approach in the other question misses is capturing the attitude that you're interested in. My (too brief) googling on the matter shows that most people use a quaternion approach to solve the problem you're interested in.  [This paper](http://mars.cs.umn.edu/tr/reports/Trawny05b.pdf) has an approach using the Kalman filter but a) it assumes gyros for rotational velocity measurement and b) it actually doesn't show data with the derived KF applied, so I'm skeptical about whether it worked.