# Reduce Jitter in Live Kalman Filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, python, kalman-filters, filtering

I have a stream of data over time that I have fed into a Kalman filter. This data represents the vertical displacement in time of a vehicle's rearwheel as it travels over a bump in the road. The wheels are being detected through video processing.

How can I fine tune my algorithm to reduce the sawtooth jitter that the Kalman filter gives me?

[image]

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
from numpy import ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# The numpy.ma module provides a convenient way to address the issue of dropout, with masked arrays.
# When an element of the mask is False, the corresponding element of the associated array is valid and is said to be unmasked.
# When an element of the mask is True, the corresponding element of the associated array is said to be masked (invalid).
rearwheel_y = ma.masked_values(rearwheel_y, 0)

# time step
dt = 1
# initial_state_mean
X0 = rearwheel_y[0]
# initial_state_covariance
P0 = 0
n_timesteps = len(rearwheel_y)
n_dim_state = 1
filtered_state_means = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state))
filtered_state_covariances = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state, n_dim_state))
# Kalman-Filter initialization
kf = KalmanFilter()
# iterative estimation for each new measurement
for t in range(n_timesteps):
    if t == 0:
        filtered_state_means[t] = X0
        filtered_state_covariances[t] = P0
    elif t != 0:
        filtered_state_means[t], filtered_state_covariances[t] = (
        kf.filter_update(
            filtered_state_means[t-1],
            filtered_state_covariances[t-1],
            observation = rearwheel_y[t])
        )

# plot of the resulting trajectory
plt.figure()
plt.plot(rearwheel_y, 'k.', label = 'Observations')
plt.plot(filtered_state_means[:, 0], "g-", label="Filtered Positions", markersize=1)
plt.ylim(150, 205)
plt.grid()
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

Comment: Given that your observations are quantized in steps of 10 whatevers (you *could* label your axes) I think you're doing pretty good.  I'm not sure you could improve things much without getting more resolution out of your observations.

Comment: Could you share the dynamic model?

Comment: @TimWescott thank you for your input.

Comment: @Royi, where could I go to help me figure out the dynamic model? I am self-teaching and hope to learn as fully as I can.

Comment: The matrices you used in the code. Could you write them in the question in LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start the right way (as Tim's comment says): let's start with the signal model of what you're doing.

Let's assume that the measurements at time $k$ are just positions $x_k$ and $y_k$ and that these are also part of the state, which also includes $\dot{x}_k$, $\dot{y}_k$, $\ddot{x}_k$, and $\ddot{y}_k$:
$$
\mathbf{x}_k = \left[   x_k \ \dot{x}_k \  \ddot{x}_k \ y_k \  \dot{y}_k \  
 \ddot{y}_k   \right]^T
$$

Then the output equation is
$$
\mathbf{z}_k = \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_k + \epsilon_k = \left [ x_k\ y_k \right ]^T + \epsilon_k
$$
with
$$
\mathbf{H}  = \left [  \begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right ]
$$
and $\epsilon_k$ is the measurement noise and it is distributed jointly normally with zero mean and covariance $\mathbf{R}$ ([called the `observation_covariance` in `pykalman`](https://pykalman.github.io/#mathematical-formulation)). The `observation_matrices` is what $\mathbf{H}$ is called in `pykalman`.

The state update equation will then just be
$$
\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_k + \mathbf{B} \eta_k
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the state transition matrix and $\eta_k$ is the process noise.

For a standard displacement, velocity, acceleration model driven by noisy jerk inputs, this means:
$$
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &=& x_k + \Delta T \dot{x}_k + \frac{1}{2} \Delta T^2 \\
\dot{x}_{k+1} &=& \dot{x}_k + \Delta T \ddot{x}_k \\
\ddot{x}_{k+1} &=& \ddot{x}_k + \eta_k
\end{align}
$$
with similar expressions for $y$.

That means
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & \Delta T & \frac{1}{2} \Delta T^2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & \Delta T& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta T & \frac{1}{2} \Delta T^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta T\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{B} = \left [
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right ]
$$

Then the process noise covariance is $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^T \Sigma_\eta$ where $\Sigma_\eta$ is the covariance of $\eta_k$. This is called the `transition_covariance` in `pykalman`.

If I do that and take some guesses for the process and measurement noise scales, then I get the result below.

[image: Latest result]

As you can see, the early part of the plot gets perturbed by missing data.  I'm not quite sure the best way to deal with that.

## New Code below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
from numpy import ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Reading data
observations = pd.read_csv('Q66687.csv')
rearwheel_y = observations['rearwheel_y'].to_list()
rearwheel_x = observations['rearwheel_x'].to_list()

# Locate and clip relevant snippet of motion, removing unecessary data at the beginning and end
rearwheel_y = rearwheel_y[385: 600]
rearwheel_x = rearwheel_x[385: 600]

#rearwheel_y = np.sin(20*time) + 10

# The numpy.ma module provides a convenient way to address the issue of dropout, with masked arrays.
# When an element of the mask is False, the corresponding element of the associated array 
# is valid and is said to be unmasked.
# When an element of the mask is True, the corresponding element of the associated array 
# is said to be masked (invalid).
rearwheel_x = ma.masked_values(rearwheel_x, 0)
rearwheel_y = ma.masked_values(rearwheel_y, 0)
measurements = np.array([rearwheel_x, rearwheel_y])

# initial_state_mean
Xbar = np.array([rearwheel_x[0],0,0,rearwheel_y[0],0,0]).transpose();
# initial_state_covariance
P0 = 100*np.identity(6)
n_timesteps = len(measurements[0])
n_dim_state = 6
filtered_state_means = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state))
filtered_state_covariances = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state, n_dim_state))

# Kalman-Filter initialization
DeltaT = 0.01668335
A = np.array([[1, DeltaT, 0.5*DeltaT**2, 0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 1, DeltaT, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, DeltaT, 0.5*DeltaT**2], 
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, DeltaT], 
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
B = np.array([[0, 0],
             [0, 0],
             [1, 0],
             [0, 0],
             [0, 0],
             [0, 1],])
SigmaEta = np.array([[1,0], [0,1]]) # Assume eta covariance is unit...
#Q = B @ B.transpose() * 0.0001
Q = np.identity(6) * 0.00001
R = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])*0.00005
H = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0]])              
kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = A,
                  observation_matrices = H,
                  transition_covariance = Q,
                  observation_covariance = R,
                  initial_state_mean = Xbar,
                  initial_state_covariance = P0)
# iterative estimation for each new measurement
for t in range(n_timesteps):
    if t == 0:
        filtered_state_means[t] = Xbar
        filtered_state_covariances[t] = P0
    elif t != 0:
        filtered_state_means[t], filtered_state_covariances[t] = (
        kf.filter_update(
            filtered_state_means[t-1],
            filtered_state_covariances[t-1],
            observation = measurements[:,t])
        )

# plot of the resulting trajectory
plt.figure()
plt.plot(rearwheel_y, 'k.', label = 'Observations')
plt.plot(filtered_state_means[:, 3], "y-", label="Filtered Positions", markersize=1)
plt.ylim(180, 200)
plt.grid()
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

---

## Older version below

OK, so if you change your Kalman filter to something like this:

```
kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = np.array([[0.1,0.9], [0, 1]]),
                  observation_matrices = np.array([[1., 0]]),
                  transition_covariance = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1]]),
                  observation_covariance = np.array([[100]]),
                  initial_state_mean = np.array([[0,0]]),
                  initial_state_covariance = np.array([[0.13, 0], [0, 0.13]]))
```

you get:

[image: New version with different parameters]

You can change the `observation_covariance` up or down to get smoother or more jagged tracks. The smoother tracks will have more delay.

---

## Original post

To get anything more sensible out of it, you'll have to choose a better model.  The model you chose before your recent edit had that the measurement changed as a simple random walk.  If that's all you know about how the measurement changes, then what you have is as good as it gets.

If you know more, for example if the measurement has some inertia, then you will need to choose different parameters, especially for your transition matrix.

Without understanding a bit more about what your measurements are, I won't be able to help much. Have a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8869/80) and see if that helps.  That answer looks at including position and velocity into the state, so that the `transition_matrices` parameter is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

I couldn't load your data sensibly, so I just generated an offset sinusoid and changed the KF parameters.  This can yield something like the plot below.  However, I'd need to know more about your signal model to get it to work sensibly for your situation.

[image: Example output]

---

**Updated Code Below**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
from numpy import ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Add time
time = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 201)

# Locate and clip relevant snippet of motion, removing unecessary data at the beginning and end
#rearwheel_y = rearwheel_y[385: 600]

rearwheel_y = np.sin(20*time) + 10

# The numpy.ma module provides a convenient way to address the issue of dropout, with masked arrays.
# When an element of the mask is False, the corresponding element of the associated array is valid and is said to be unmasked.
# When an element of the mask is True, the corresponding element of the associated array is said to be masked (invalid).
# rearwheel_y = ma.masked_values(rearwheel_y, 0)

# time step
dt = 1
# initial_state_mean
X0 = 0 #rearwheel_y[0]
# initial_state_covariance
P0 = 0
n_timesteps = len(rearwheel_y)
n_dim_state = 2
filtered_state_means = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state))
filtered_state_covariances = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state, n_dim_state))
# Kalman-Filter initialization
kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = np.array([[0.01,0.99], [0, 1]]),
                  observation_matrices = np.array([[1., 0]]),
                  transition_covariance = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1]]),
                  observation_covariance = np.array([[1000]]),
                  initial_state_mean = np.array([[0,0]]),
                  initial_state_covariance = np.array([[0.3, 0], [0, 0.3]]))
# iterative estimation for each new measurement
for t in range(n_timesteps):
    if t == 0:
        filtered_state_means[t] = X0
        filtered_state_covariances[t] = P0
    elif t != 0:
        filtered_state_means[t], filtered_state_covariances[t] = (
        kf.filter_update(
            filtered_state_means[t-1],
            filtered_state_covariances[t-1],
            observation = rearwheel_y[t])
        )

# plot of the resulting trajectory
plt.figure()
plt.plot(rearwheel_y, 'k.', label = 'Observations')
plt.plot(filtered_state_means[:, 0], "y-", label="Filtered Positions", markersize=1)
plt.ylim(8, 12)
plt.grid()
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have modified my post to include a link to the downloadable data set as well as the lines of the code that allow it to be imported. I have also inlcuded a decsription of what the measurements mean. I am self-teaching myself this Kalman Filter method and based on my edits would appreciate advice on how to change the model based on this situation. I am not clear on how I should set up my matrices or what to populate them with. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Is there any way to derive these values in order to be more "correct" or are they usually set randomly through fine-tuning? I'd like to gain a better understanding and am self-teaching myself this method, so excuse my naivity. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrea. You're welcome! I'll try to edit this later today and add a bit more.  This week is busy, but I should have some time this afternoon (8 or so hours away).  Feel free to ping me here tomorrow if I don't.

Comment: The theoretically correct way to construct a Kalman filter is to come up with an accurate dynamical model of your system, and then just build a filter from it.  This takes a good understanding of the system you're modeling, and how to model it.  The *other* way to design a Kalman is to make some guesses about how the system works, and jigger parameters until you get what you want.  Given that the power of the Kalman filter is that it's optimal to the degree that the model is correct, I consider this to be a "fake Kalman" -- but it *can* work.

Comment: @TimWescott Agreed!  I'm definitely taking the *fake Kalman* approach above.  I'm hoping I have time to do it the right way later... but I'll have to make assumptions about the dynamics that I'm not getting enough information about.

Comment: @PeterK., many thanks for your time. I'd like to provide as much information about the dynamics as I can. As mentioned in the post, the values represent the vertical displacement of the center of a vehicle's rear wheel from a horizontal datum that lies above the center of the wheel. The vehilce is moving at a constant speed for the entire span and is driven over a bump in the road. This explains why the 'bump' in the plot.

Comment: @Andrea I'm wondering what `rearwheel_r` is in the CSV file?

Comment: @PeterK. those are radii from the detection output that don't quite have a meaning with respect to the Kalman issue. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterK. thank you so much for your updates to this problem and for your help and time!

Comment: @Andrea Thanks.  I've made an attempt to do a less *fake* version. See my edits.  You're welcome!